# React - passing props to a component recieved in props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react and I am faced with a problem.

I have a component that needs to accept another component as prop, and pass into the same component other props.
Example:

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div onClick={this.props.onClick}>Some content.</div>)
    }
}

Item.propTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default class Container extends React.Component {
    onClick() {
        // Do something.
    }
    render() {
        // render here the item and passing it my onClick method.
    }
}

Container.propTypes = {
    item: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

Edit:
So I probably can use the es5 syntax and do something like this:

```
React.createElement(item, {
    onClick: this.onClick
});
```

But how can I achieve that in es6?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do, if you need to pass all props, you can use spread operator too.

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.handleClick}>Some content.>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

Item.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default class Container extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const handleClick = () => {
      // Do something.
    }
    // render here the item and passing it my onClick method.
    render () {
      return (
        <Item handleClick={handleClick} />
      );
    }
  }
}

Container.propTypes = {
  item: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Can you really do that? I mean you are passing an actual element inside the <> that doesnt sound right

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in to Container, the Item component type and the props you want to assign instead of an instance.  This is so that you can add more props before creating the instance

Then you can do like so:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        ItemType: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        itemProps: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    onItemClick = () => {
       // do something
    };

    render() {
        const { ItemType, itemProps } = this.props;
        return <ItemType {...itemProps} onClick={this.onItemClick} />;
    }
}

class MyDisplay extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const ItemToRender = someCondition ? Item : AnotherItem;
        return <Container ItemType={ItemToRender} itemProps={{a: 1, b: 2}} />;
    }
}
```